# Find and Replace on row1 google sheets function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Very new to this, I am trying to Find and Replace on row1 only

I want to find `aa` and replace it with `ZZZ`

I am trying two different ways but neither work

Thanks

first way:

```
function replace3() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var lc = sheet.getMaxColumns();
 var range = sheet.getRange("a1:z1");
 var values = range.getValues();

 for (var col in values[1]) {
   if (values[0][col] ='aa') {
      values[0][col] = 'ZZZ';
   }
 }
 range.setValues(values);
}
```

Second Way:

```
function replace2() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var lc = sheet.getMaxColumns();
 var range = sheetname.getRange(1, 1, 1, lc);
 var values = range.getValues();
   for (var i = 0; i <= lc; i++) {
      if (values[0][i] ='aa') {
        values[0][i] = 'ZZZ';
      }
  }
 range.setValues(values);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following modofications?

### For `replace3()`

- The index of array starts 0.
- When values are compared at `if`, please use `==`.

#### Modified script :

```
function replace3() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var lc = sheet.getMaxColumns();
 var range = sheet.getRange("a1:z1");
 var values = range.getValues();

 for (var col in values[0]) { // Modified
   if (values[0][col] =='aa') { // Modified
      values[0][col] = 'ZZZ';
   }
 }
 range.setValues(values);
}
```

### For `replace2()`

- `sheetname` is not declared.
- When values are compared at `if`, please use `==`.

#### Modified script :

```
function replace2() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var lc = sheet.getMaxColumns();
 var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, lc); // Modified
 var values = range.getValues();
 for (var i = 0; i <= lc; i++) {
   if (values[0][i] == 'aa') { // Modified
     values[0][i] = 'ZZZ';
   }
 }
 range.setValues(values);
}
```

### Other method :

Also you can achieve it using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

#### Sample script :

```
function sample() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var range = sheet.getRange("a1:z1");
 var values = range.getValues();
 var data = values[0].map(function(e){return e == 'aa' ? 'ZZZ' : e});
 range.setValues([data]);
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify.

Comment: @Tim Welcome. Thank you, too.